# Codename one crashes on device only

Tags: codenameone

I have a codenameone app that works fine in the desktop emulator (windows 7) but when I run it on my Xperia Z1 (android) it crashes when I try to show a new form (this has been working fine).

I am currently using the free account and so do not get crash reports (e.g. a call stack). And it'll take me forever to keep trial-and-error hoping to find it ....

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Android SDK, connect your device with a cable and launch the DDMS tool to connect to the device. You should be able to see the log messages and stack trace thru that and it might give you a better indication of what is going on.